# AsyncTask and SOAP webservices

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-asynctask, android-studio-2.3

I'm new to SOAP webservices and AsyncTask, I'm developing an app which is using SOAP webservices for login.
I tried to do all work in onCreate method but I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

So i tried to use AsyncTask,
but I'm not able to get reference to emailText and passwordText in RetrieveFeedTask class.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "intentionally hided";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "intentionally hided";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "intentionally hided";
    private static String URL = "intentionally hided";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        final EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("userName", emailText.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty("userPassword", passwordText.getText().toString());

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                if (result != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems there is an article here -> http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data explaining how to do this. However, i would look into json and rest API's instead of SOAP Webservices if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this (AsyncTask with onPreExecute and onPostExecute, but without NetworkOnMainThreadException):

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("userName", emailText.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("userPassword", passwordText.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            if (result != null) {
                result = "Login Successful!";
            } else {
                result = "Login Failed!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.equals("Login Successful!")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got a solution before also I tried your solution, It worked like charm.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the text value of the views into the constructor of the async task and access them via the inner reference.

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String emailText, passwordText;

    RetrieveFeedTask(String emailText, String passwordText) {
        this.emailText = emailText;
        this.passwordText = passwordText;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
 new RetrieveFeedTask(
        emailText.getText().toString(), 
        passwordText.getText().toString()
 ).execute();
```

Alternatively, you could pass parameters directly to `doInBackground()` as an array.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String email = urls[0];    
    String password = urls[1]; 
    ....  
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
String[] urls = { 
    emailText.getText().toString(), 
    passwordText.getText().toString() 
};

new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(urls);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I did same but problem is still there saying "method getText must be called from UI Thread".

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question. I have updated my answer. You cannot modify the state of a view from a non UI thread. The reason you get that error is because doInBackground() runs on a non UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem but now its saying there should be something returned from doInBackground method while i have nothing to return, Can you help in this regard?

Comment: No problem. Try changing class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask`<String, String, String>` to class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask`<String, String, Void>`. The third type is the return type of `doInBackground()`, so you will then need to change `String doInBackground()` to `Void doInBackground()` and modify the method to return null.

Comment: class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
and also changed return type to void of doInBackground but still its giving error at void
protected void doInBacground 
Error; attempting to use incomplete return type

Comment: Are you returning Void (class) or void (primitive)? Generics do not support primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

You pass emailText and passwordText directly into the AsyncTask, you just need to make a few minor changes:

First in your onClick Listener:

String email = emailText.getText().toString();

String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(email, password);

Second in your AsyncTask doInBackground Method:

String email = urls[0];

String password = urls[1];

Pretty much you can pass arbitrary values into the execute method of AsyncTask which are received as parameters in it's doInBackground method.